# How to grant permissions to android instrumented tests?

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, permissions, android-instrumentation

I have an application that reads SMSs. The app works fine when debugging but when testing it using android instrumented test it throws the following error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.telephony.SmsProvider
```

This is my test case

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class SmsFetcherTest {

   @Test
   public void fetchTenSms() throws Exception {
      // Context of the app under test.
      Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();

      //   Fails anyway.
      //   assertTrue(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(appContext,
      //     "android.permission.READ_SMS") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

      List<Sms> tenSms = new SmsFetcher(appContext)
              .limit(10)
              .get();

      assertEquals(10, tenSms.size());
   }
}
```

I'm new to instrumented tests. Is this is proper way to do this?

Or am I missing something?

Comment: InstrumentationRegistry.getContext() doesn't return the Context of the app under test. To get it, use InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().

Answer (score 45):

Use [`GrantPermissionRule`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/GrantPermissionRule). Here's how:

Add the following dependency to `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
}
```

Now add the following to your `InstrumentedTest` class:

```
import androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule;

public class InstrumentedTest {
    @Rule
    public GrantPermissionRule mRuntimePermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
    ...
}
```

Comment: [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/GrantPermissionRule) link, dependency `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'`

Comment: For me seems like this rule doesn't matter, permissions validation is always returning true.

Comment: @Akhha8 same but if I want it to return false?

Answer (score 11):

You can grant the permission as follows:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MyInstrumentationTest {
    @Rule
    public GrantPermissionRule permissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
    ...

}
```

Comment: Couldn't find class GrantPermissionRule. 
Please provide the package.

Comment: [check this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/GrantPermissionRule)

Comment: @JavaBanana import android.support.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule; in our test class

Comment: can't find anything in `Manifest.permission` for USB device access permission. Any suggestions?

Comment: It should be `android.Manifest.permission` not `Manifest.permission`

Answer (score 1):

If you use inheritance for instrumentation classes you should write `@get:Rule` in parent class.

For location:

```
import androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
open class SomeTest {
    @get:Rule
    val permissionRule: GrantPermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
```

If you add `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` on device where Android < Q or permission that doesn't exist in AndroidManifest you will get [an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903976/grantpermissionrule-failed-to-grant-permissions).

Answer (score 1):

For reusability I create an interface:

```
interface WriteExternalPermission {

    @get:Rule val writeExternalPermission: GrantPermissionRule
        get() = GrantPermissionRule.grant(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

}
```

And you can just implement it inside your test class, where this permission is needed.

Answer (score 0):

For some permissions Rules are not working - like Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH. Not sure why.

Workaround is to use Mockito and mock Context - so when context.checkSelfPermission() is called by system it simply returns Permission Granted

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

private Context mockedContext;
private final String[] permissionArrayOne = new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        "android.permission.BLUETOOTH",
        "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN",
        "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"};

@Before
public void setup(){
    mockedContext = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
    Mockito.when(mockedContext.checkPermission(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
            ArgumentMatchers.anyInt(),
            ArgumentMatchers.anyInt())).thenReturn(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}

 @Test
 public void myPermTest() {
    for (String onePerm : permissionArrayOne) {
        Log.d(TAG, "myPermTest: " + onePerm + " " + mockedContext.checkSelfPermission(onePerm));
        assertEquals(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mockedContext, onePerm), PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }
}
}
```