# Running recorded espresso test result in error

Tags: java, android, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

When I run a recorded espresso test I get the following error:

junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Failed to grant permissions, see logcat for details
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
at androidx.test.runner.permission.PermissionRequester.requestPermissions(PermissionRequester.java:111)
at androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule$RequestPermissionStatement.evaluate(GrantPermissionRule.java:133)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1939)

I have the following dependencies in espresso:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

I am running these test on a T2 Mini from sunmi, and some of the suggested solutions are in the links below:
[GrantPermissionRule Failed to grant permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903976/grantpermissionrule-failed-to-grant-permissions) I do not have that option in the developer option of this device

Comment: read the error message

Comment: @Psytho I kind did, the current suggestion where to allow USB debugging(security settings) but the device that I have does not have that option.