# I want to automatically click the permission window on Android

Tags: android

I want to automatically create a consent button when the permission window is displayed on Android

I clicked on the root view, but clicked the main view instead of the permission window
Click on the permission window

```
private void autoClick(float x, float y) {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }

    // Obtain MotionEvent object
    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    int metaState = 0;
    MotionEvent keyDown = MotionEvent.obtain(
            downTime,
            eventTime,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
            x,
            y,
            metaState
    );

    MotionEvent keyUp = MotionEvent.obtain(
            downTime,
            eventTime,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
            x,
            y,
            metaState
    );

    //keyDown.setSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN);
    //keyUp.setSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN);

    getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().dispatchTouchEvent(keyDown);
    getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().dispatchTouchEvent(keyUp);

    //findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView().dispatchTouchEvent(keyDown);
    //findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView().dispatchTouchEvent(keyUp);
}
```

Comment: Is this for a test, or intended to automatically grant yourself the permission in the app itself?

Comment: It's for testing, but it's also for getting permission.

Comment: So, you definitely can't do this outside of a test, because if you _could_, that would defeat the entire point of a permission prompt.

Comment: Thank you for answer
I want to click on a specific location like an auto clicker
Is it impossible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to grant permissions to android instrumented tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403128/how-to-grant-permissions-to-android-instrumented-tests)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reliably simulate touch events on Android without root (like Automate and Tasker)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775698/how-can-i-reliably-simulate-touch-events-on-android-without-root-like-automate)