# How to grant permission in flutter integration tests?

Tags: android, flutter, android-instrumentation, flutter-integration-test

I have setup integration tests for [firebase using guide](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/main/packages/integration_test#android-device-testing). I am running the same tests at local using following command:

```
  flutter build apk --debug --flavor dev
  ./gradlew app:assembleDevDebugAndroidTest
  ./gradlew app:connectedDevDebugAndroidTest -Ptarget=integration_test/main_test.dart
```

I'm able to run tests successfully but the apk asks for permissions if it's new device or reinstalled the app.

I added following code to `flutter_app/android/app/src/androidTest/java/com/domain/myapp/MainActivityTest.java` to [implement GrantPermissionRule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51969705/1779027) as mentioned still it didn't work.

```
@RunWith(FlutterTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> rule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, true, false);

    @Rule
    public GrantPermissionRule mRuntimePermissionRule =
        GrantPermissionRule.grant(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    );
}
```

[image: Permissions]
Is there a way to grant permissions in Flutter Instrumentation tests?

Answer (score 0):

In driver folder test_driver/integration_test:
Below example is to accept permission for location and similarly you can add other permissions also using adb for android

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test_driver.dart';
                
        future<void> main() async {
        final adbPath = path.join(
              androidHomePath,
              'platform-tools',
              Platform.isWindows ? 'adb.exe' : 'adb',
            );
              await process.run(
               'adbPath',
               [
                 'shell',
                 'pm',
                 'grant',
                 'com.example.<your app name>', // todo: update this
                 'android.permission.access_coarse_location'
               ],
             );
         await process.run(
               'adbPath',
               [
                 'shell',
                 'pm',
                 'grant',
                 'com.example.<your app name>', // todo: update this
                 'android.permission.READ_CONTACTS'
               ],
             );
             // todo: add more permissions as required
             await integrationdriver();
            }
```

Comment: This I'm doing when running at local as this `adb` commands works when debigging. But in case of running tests via `gradle connectedDevDebugAndroidTest` it doesn't work.